# Как можно быстро построить дерево директорий?

Tags: c#, .net

В общем необходимо обойти директории в указанной папке и вернуть список путей к каждой директории.

Как это можно сделать наиболее быстро? Есть ли смысл в параллелизме?

Comment: Может это вам поможет https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997370(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, оформите как ответ.

Comment: паралелить особого смысла нет, все равно все упрется в производительность доступа к диску, особенно если операция разовая.

Answer (score 2):

Может это вам поможет .

Практическое руководство. Перечисление каталогов и файлов https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997370(v=vs.110).aspx

Перечисление имен файлов в каталоге и подкаталогах

- Используйте метод [Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)
  для поиска каталог и (при необходимости) его подкаталогов, и получения списка имен файлов, соответствующих заданному шаблону поиска.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
{
    var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    from line in File.ReadLines(file)
    where line.Contains("Microsoft")
    select new
{
    File = file,
    Line = line
};

foreach (var f in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
}
catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Это ответ-ссылка. Он был бы намного ценнее, если бы вы разместили в ответе код и/или краткую выжимку идей, изложенных в статье.

Comment: @VladD Больше чем на этой страницe по ссылки я не скажу,пусть люди заходят и смотрят,можeт они найдут  решения и других задач

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan коротенький пример применительно к вопросу все же не помешает, для полноты ответа.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan,Параллелизм имеет смысл использовать? Не лучше ли руками обходить? Если EnumerateFiles упадет с ошибкой, то я не получу вообще элементов коллекции...

Comment: @iluxa1810  так обработайте эту ошибку, кто вам мешает  :)

Answer (score 0):

В предположении что есть интерфейс пользователя, в котором показан верхний уровень дерева директорий.

Можно использовать разные потоки для интерфейса пользователя и собственно заполнения дерева.

Также имеет смысл первым получить список поддиректорий в текущей директории и сразу выдать его в UI -- пользователь быстро увидит отклик. После этого уже бежать по поддиректориям -- UI от этого не изменится или почти не изменится.